# How to avoid passing Database object to each Model object without having to use global variables?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

To avoid global variables or static configuration classes, I'm passing the database object to each and every one of my models when I instantiate them:

```
$user = new User( App::getDatabase() );
if( !$user->loggedIn() ) doSomething();
```

App being a class with static members.

This is really cumbersome but the only alternative is to use the static class(or global variable) from within the model classes:

```
class User extends Model {

    function loggedIn() {
        $database = App::getDatabase();
        $database->query('stuff');
        // you get the picture
    }
}
```

But this is just like using global variables.

Another idea would be to pass the database to the parent class from which each model inherits from:

```
class Model {
    protected static $database

    public static function setDatabase($database) {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    // more stuff here
}

class User extends Model {

    function loggedIn() {
        parent::$database->query('stuff');
        // you get the picture
    }
}

Model::setDatabase($myDatabase);
```

EDIT: I just realized this last example makes all my Models depend on a single database. I can't make it to use multiple databases this way... Could be a serious limitation.

However I'm new to PHP and I havent tried this yet.

Is this a good idea? Is there any alternative out there?

Comment: I think this is a good idea!

Here might be the worst alternative - to read configuration data from a file (txt, or any *ext), each time. And all models know,where to find that file on your server.

Comment: Have you considered using an dependency injection container?

Comment: Also `User extends Model`. I don't know about your users, but most of mine look nothing like a model

Comment: Peehaa I know little about dependency injection. How would that container work? And what do you mean about a user not being a model?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code....

```
Model::$database = App::getDatabase();
```

You don't need to set it on every object since you are inheriting from Model.